# Running my website on the same sever as another site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, dns, web-hosting

*First off i'm a noob when it comes to Websites. I'm fine with the coding just never actually launched one before.*

Basically there is a website hosted on a Server built in WordPress. It is in the root directory and has its own domain lets call it example.com.

In the root directory there is a folder for my site lets call it mysite.com. mysite.com has its own domain aswell.

What DNS settings do I need to do so I can launch my website?

*Any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: Apache virtual hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Alright - Im going to flip a coin and assume that you are working with a linux web server, if you are then you are in luck.

If that is not the case, Im sorry.
Ive done all of this by the way, but Im being brief because my understanding of your environment is based entirely upon assumption

First off, you need to purchase a domain name - godaddy is cheap.

Next, you need to modify the domain name DNS A record to point to your server's external IP address.  You can find this out easily, just do a google search for how to find linux external IP.

If you are hosting the box from within a home network or behind a router, then you can use any computer connected to the router to check the external IP.  All inbound HTTP requests will travel through port 80 or 443, ill assume you dont want to deal with getting a SSL cert and dealing with a CA at this point, so you can log into your router at 192.168.1.1 if you are with any mainstream residential ISP
and forward all requests to that router on ports 80 and 443 to the INTERNAL ip of your linux box.

install apache
install php

navigate to either /etc/httpd/ or /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/  work on your conf files and you should be in good shape.

that will get you 1 website.  You need to do virtual hosting if you want multiple, and your DNS settings (A RECORDS) for each of your domains should all point to the same external IP of the linux box.  Apache will handle the rest once you set up your conf files correctly.

if you want more detail let me know, this should be on serverfault though